# What is the difference between CPU and Core temperatures?

Tags: performance, cpu, temperature

While trying to figure out why the performance of my machine has suddenly severely degraded, I noticed that although CPU temperature is being reported as 45C while idle, the temperatures of all 6 Cores is being reported as 75-80C.

I suspect these readings are correct, as my i7-3930K (3201 Mhz) is being throttled to 1600-1200 Mhz. I've also tried reconnecting everything, and continue to receive the same readings from the sensors.

What is the difference between the CPU and Core temperatures?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot or command output of how you're getting these temperatures?  The CPU value you're reading is probably from a motherboard sensor and not inside the CPU itself.  If you're on Windows, you can see the output of these sensors using HWMonitor, and lm-sensors on Linux; my i7 2600k indeed has a thermometer in each core, as well as one on the CPU package/case itself (in addition to an external sensor on the motherboard).  Ensure you're reading the correct CPU temperature value/register, avoiding inferred values like the motherboard returns.

Comment: @Breakthrough: I suspect it is from a motherboard sensor. It's consistent across hwmonitor, speedfan, throttlestop, and my motherboard manufacturer's tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPU temperatures listed by many motherboards themselves can be based on a sensor that exist under the CPU, and because that is not the actual core temps, they also have applied algorithms that attempt better to guess what the temperature might be.  This could be reading about anything, a mix of the motherboard's own heat, and the CPU heat around there, and any adjustments they made to it, could be close or miles off.  They could also be using the CPU package temperature.

The "core temperatures" listed by many programs is based on a sensor that intel has that sits right inside the die of the CPU itself, and reads the actual temperatures the CPU is having to deal with. Provided by Intel, along with providing the method of reading it, most motherboards still are not applying that for their own info and control.

A system sensor will often also exist, that can be based on a mix of the motherboard temps and ambient temps, or could be more about the main chipset temps for the I/O chips that exist on the board. All depending on how they wanted to do things.

CPU core temps are usually a reliable way to determine the CPU temps, for situations like throttling at ~100° C. 75-80° C an Intel modern processor should not be throttling. A modern Intel processor will happily downclock and down voltage at any temperatures, when it does not have a lot of work to do.

An operating system can also have some level of control of CPU scheduling stuff, in Windows that is in the power settings and advanced power options. The max and min performance and active and passive cooling items, can affect the processor stepping and aspects of the cooling (but not throttling specific). Also a motherboard's own thermal response system can be adjusted usually for the fans.

Comment: Most CPUs actually do have a temperature sensor in each core, as well as one embedded on the CPU package itself, so it is possible to obtain the proper temperature reading.  As you stated, the value being shown by OP is likely from a motherboard sensor/register as opposed to the (proper) value returned by the CPU package temperature sensor.

Comment: His use of temperatures in "All 8 cores", indicated that it was the "core temperatures", from the cpu. and Yes your right I might not have had enough information to answer.

Comment: In hwmonitor, I'm seeing `Core #[0..5]` temperatures, which I suspect are inaccurate, and a `CPUTIN` temperature, which I suspect is accurate. I'm having an issue with throttling and unrealistic temperatures, but I think it's too broad for superuser.

Comment: trying to find the datasheet, did not go well http://ark.intel.com/products/63697/Intel-Core-i7-3930K-Processor-12M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz classed as second gen, which we know has core temp sensors, the data sheet though is an all-in one for all 2nd gen, so a facted out throttling temperature i did not find.  People will recommend HWinfo over HWmonitor. Ahh different opinions abound, I use neither :-)

Comment: @dauphic `CPUTIN` is the motherboard sensor (and inaccurate on my machine), not the temperature sensor in the CPU itself.  In HWMonitor, I see `Core #[0..3]` and `Package`.  Could you maybe post a screenshot of the sensors you get?  For your reference, [here's a screenshot of what I see](http://i.imgur.com/sP5E2sc.png) that shows both sensors.